# Resume download after killing or putting on background the application

Tags: ios, download, alamofire

I have some issues when I want to resume a download operation. I am using Alamofire 4.4 and I made my tests on iOS 9 and 10.
Here is my use cases:

1- A download operation is in progress, I cancel the request (`resumeData` is generated and saved) and then I put the application on background. After relaunching the application, I resume the download (using the `resumeData`) some times the download is being resumed and sometimes is being restarted.
Is it a normal behaviour ? And are there any solution if not ?

2- A download operation is in progress, and i kill the application. Downloaded data seems to be lost and I can't resume the download.
Is there any solution to get the resumeData and resume the download after restarting the application ?

Thank you.

Comment: I think Alamofire supports this feature without using anything.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Finally I have reimplemented the download module using URLSession. My application is more stable now.

Comment: Yes, using URLSession.

Comment: Can you please post the code? Code may be helpful for everyone.